# Probability that a given function is prime...

Tags: probability, proof-verification, prime-numbers

If we have a set of primes $p_1$, $p_2$, ... , $p_n$, we can easily construct a function of their product:

$$f(\alpha) = \alpha \left( \prod_{k=1}^n{p_k} \right) + 1, \alpha \in \mathbb{N}$$

I'm wondering what the probability is that this function equals a prime.  I want to say that since a random number $y$ seems to be prime with probability $1 / \log{(y)}$, we can conclude that $f(\alpha)$ is prime with probability $\ge 1/\log{(f(\alpha))}$.  Is this correct?  Either way, I'm hoping that someone can prove and/or show the probability of $f(\alpha)$ being prime.

I am assuming that all $p_k$ are less than $\beta$.

Note that I'm trying to prove that $f(\alpha)$ is prime with probability at least some value - in other words, I'm trying to find a lower bounds.

Comment: We assume $\alpha\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: @GregoryGrant: yes.

Comment: What probability distribution are you using?

Comment: @MarcPaul:  I'm doing this over the natural numbers, and the primes $p_k$ are assumed to be chosen at random (i.e. equally or evenly distributed) from all primes less than $\beta$.  I hope this answers your question.

Comment: @MattGroff: And $\alpha$ and $n$ are fixed constants? By the way, I'm not sure if it makes sense to ask if the chance of $f(\alpha)$ being prime is more than $1/\mathrm{log}(f(\alpha))$, because the last clearly depends on $f(\alpha)$, which we treat as stochastic. But I could be wrong, I don't know a lot about probability theory.

Comment: @MarcPaul:  Yes, $\alpha$ and $n$ are fixed constants.